# Is there any limitation from SharePoint online on indexing large PDF files

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, limitations, boundaries

I want to start a new project, which basically include uploading large PDF files and be able to search them. when i say large PDF files i am referring to either in respect to number of pages which can goes beyond 500,000 pages in a single file OR in respect to the file size which can also exceed 1/2 GB for a single file OR both of them of-course.

So SharePoint Online is one of the options to implement this project. but my question is if there is a any limitation in SharePoint online on large PDF files? either in uploading them and/or searching them/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PDF files are included in the file size limit：

File upload limit is 250 GB -Applies to each individual file uploaded to Microsoft Teams Files tab, SharePoint document libraries, OneDrive folders, and Yammer conversations.

The Maximum value of parsed content size is 2 million characters, Search stops parsing an item if it has parsed up to 2 million characters of content from it, any unparsed content isn't processed and therefore isn't indexed.

More information for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search-limits